# How can I create this in Photoshop or Gimp?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, effects, borders

Can you help me with this? I would like to learn how to create the depth effect in the borders of the hole in the glass. I tried bump mapping, but didn't get the exact effect. Searched for glass frame, and a guy had a plug-in, but it also created a glass texture, which was different. The thing is I'm no expert, don't know technical terminology and English is not even my first language, so I've ran out of options.
For the glass I'm using gaussian blur, then I cut the shape I want off the glass, but now I'm stuck at the depth thing, the way the right side of the border has light and the left size has shadow so that the glass looks thick instead of a hole in a parchment paper. Thanks in advance.

[image: what I want]

And this is what happened when I tried bump mapping (not quite the same):
[image: not quite the same]

Comment: I've changed the post. Hope it's better explained.

Comment: Looks like you just need to add an inner drop shadow to the text and you'll be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if anyone wonders:
With *Chris* help I've added an inner drop shadow in black to the text.
The shadow inside the text made the image behind look like a plain photo with a glass on top of it, instead of a view behind a window.
So, using the same logic, I made the black shadow smoother and thinner, only enough to add a little depth to the glass and added an outer drop shadow in white, by inverting selection and then putting the opoosite values for X and Y (before it was 4;4, now it's -4;-4), and that gave the borders of the letters some light, just like... a border.
This is the result (I know it's nothing major, and the borders are not smooth enough, but...):
[image: final image]